# How to calculate number of hops between sourcee and destination?

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query, hierarchical-query

I have two columns in a table source and destination as below.

```
source delivery
  s1      d1
  d1      d2
  d2      f1
  s2      d3
  d3      d4
  d4      d5
  d5      f2

  source - s1 destination f1
  source - s2 destination f2
```

How do I get the count of number of stops between source and destination ?
For ex: source s1 -> destination f1 has 3 stops between them and
        source s2 -> destination f2 has 4 stops between them

I am familiar with SQL queries but never had written or encountered a problem like this.
Could anyone let me know how can I write a sql query for the aforementioned problem ? 
Even if there is another question with the same problem, that link/question could help me a lot in understanding how to write it.

Comment: You need a recursive CTE for this in MySQL, which is available only in MySQL 8+.

Comment: Other options include joining the table to itself as often as could ever possibly be required, switching to a nested set model, or handling the recursion in application level code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with a recursive query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select source, delivery, 1 hops 
    from mytable t
    where not exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.delivery = t.source)
    union all 
    select c.source, t.delivery, c.hops + 1
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t.source = c.delivery
)
select source, delivery, hops
from cte c
where hops = (select max(c1.hops) from cte c1 where c1.source = c.source)
```

The anchor of the recursive query is nodes that have no incoming link; then, it walks each path, while keeping track of the original nodes and of the count of hops. Finally, the outer query filters on the last node per path.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd4d701a30d0122b708bb5d0c83340cb)**:

```
source | delivery | hops
:----- | :------- | ---:
s1     | f1       |    3
s2     | f2       |    4
```